# PowerBuilder 12.5 sql cursors transaction size error

Tags: sql, cursor, powerbuilder

i have a major problem and trying to find a workaround. I have an application in PB12.5 that works on both sql and oracle dbs.. (with a lot of data)

and i m using CURSOR at a point,, but the aplications crashes only in sql. Using debuging in PB i found that the sql connection returs -1 due to huge transaction size. But i want to fetch row by row my data.. is any work around to fetch data like paging?? i mean  lets fetch the first 1000 rows next the other 1000 and so on.. i hope that you understand what i want to achieve (to break the fetch process and so to reduce the transaction size if possible) , here is my code

```
DECLARE trans_Curs CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT associate_trans.trans_code  
 FROM associate_trans  
WHERE associate_trans.usage_code = :ggs_vars.usage  ORDER BY associate_trans.trans_code ;

  OPEN trans_Curs;
  FETCH  trans_Curs INTO :ll_transId;

  DO WHILE sqlca.sqlcode = 0
  ll_index += 1
        hpb_1.Position = ll_index
        if not guo_associates.of_asstrans_updatemaster( ll_transId, ls_error) then
        ROLLBACK;
        CLOSE trans_Curs;
      SetPointer(Arrow!)
      MessageBox("Update Process", "Problem with the update process on~r~n" + sqlca.sqlerrtext)
    cb_2.Enabled = TRUE
    return
 end if
 FETCH trans_Curs INTO :ll_transId;
 LOOP
 CLOSE trans_Curs;
```

Comment: You can add a limit to your query with two values, starting and ending condition (e.g. starting condition would be current timestamp - it relevant, otherwise any other relevant condition; ending condition would be number of rows. After  the first result, get the timestamp (or selected value) as starting condition and re-issue the select with the same number of rows. And so forth...

Comment: Thank you FDavidov  for your post, can you give me an example on my posted sample ?

Comment: Too long for a comment, so I'll put it as an answer in few minutes.

Comment: Unrleated, but: "*both sql and oracle dbs*" doesn't make sense. Oracle **is** a "SQL database"  as it uses SQL. Every relational database is a "SQL database"

Comment: sorry about that,, but i think that developers are understanding straight away the difference,, ok my bad,,, its both MS Sql and oracle dbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you FDavidov for your effort, so i managed to do it using dynamic datastore instead of cursor,, so here is my solution in case someone else need this.

```
    String ls_sql, ls_syntax, ls_err
    Long ll_row
    DataStore lds_info      

    ls_sql = "SELECT associate_trans.trans_code  "  &
                + " FROM associate_trans " &
                + "  WHERE  associate_trans.usage_code = '" + ggs_vars.usage +"' "&
                + " ORDER BY associate_trans.trans_code"
    ls_syntax = SQLCA.SyntaxFromSQL( ls_sql, "", ls_err )

    IF ls_err <> '' THEN
    MessageBox( 'Error...', ls_err )
    RETURN
    END IF

    lds_info = CREATE DataStore
    lds_info.Create( ls_syntax, ls_err )
    lds_info.SetTransObject( SQLCA )
    lds_info.Retrieve( )        

        DO WHILE sqlca.sqlcode = 0 and ll_row <= ll_count               
                FOR ll_row = 1 TO ll_count
                    ll_transId = lds_info.GetItemNumber( ll_row, 'trans_code' )                         
                        ll_index += 1
                        hpb_1.Position = ll_index
                        do while yield(); loop
                        if not guo_associates.of_asstrans_updatemaster( ll_transId, ls_error) then
                            ROLLBACK;
                            DESTROY lds_info
                            SetPointer(Arrow!)
                            MessageBox("Update Process", "Problem with the update process on~r~n" + sqlca.sqlerrtext)
                            cb_2.Enabled = TRUE
                            return
                        end if              
                    NEXT
                    DESTROY lds_info                    
        LOOP
```

Comment: its a different approach from my initial question, BUT by far is the best solution in the cursor problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure of your source table s not fully presented, I'll make some assumptions here.

Let's assume that the records include a unique field that can be used as a reference (could be a counter or a timestamp). I'll assume here that the field is a timestamp.

Let's also assume that PB accepts cursors with parameters (not all solutions do; if it does not, there are simple workarounds).

You could modify your cursor to be something like:

**[Note: I'm assuming also that the syntax presented here is valid for your environment; if not, adaptations are simple]**

```
DECLARE TopTime TIMESTAMP ;
DECLARE trans_Curs CURSOR FOR 
         SELECT ots.associate_trans.trans_code  
           FROM ots.associate_trans  
          WHERE ots.associate_trans.usage_code = :ggs_vars.usage
            AND ots.associate_trans.Timestamp  < TopTime
          ORDER BY ots.associate_trans.trans_code 
          LIMIT 1000 ;
:
:
IF (p_Start_Timestamp IS NULL) THEN
    TopTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ;
ELSE
    TopTime = p_Start_Timestamp  ;
END IF ;

OPEN trans_Curs;
FETCH  trans_Curs INTO :ll_transId;
:
:
```

In the above:

1. `p_Start_Timestamp` is a received timestamp parameter which would initially be empty and then will contain the OLDEST timestamp fetched in the previous invocation,
2. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` is a function of your environment returning the current timestamp.

This solution will work solely when you need to progress in one direction (i.e. from present to past) and that you are accumulating all the fetched records in an internal buffer in case you need to *scroll* up again.

Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Thank you FDavidov for your post. But here is a thing, my table ots.associate_trans does not have a unique field except the trans_code. So no counter or timestampfield are exists. if they were exist everything would be easier.  So this answer unfortunatelly is not applicable.

Comment: I tried a workaround with row_number instead of cursor , but this is applicable only in sql, in oracle it doesnt work, also it seems that my cursors transaction size problem is happening only in sql.

Comment: You didn't mention it was Oracle. Which version of Oracle are you using?